# GSAP repeated stagger loop

Tags: javascript, gsap

I have the 3 following HTML elements:

```
<div class="item"><h2>Item 1</h2></div>
<div class="item"><h2>Item 2</h2></div>
<div class="item"><h2>Item 3</h2></div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
var timeline = new TimelineMax({paused:true, repeat: -1});
timeline.staggerFromTo($('.item'), 1, {css:{x: -20, opacity: 0}, delay: 0.15, ease:Elastic.easeOut}, 0.5);
timeline.play();
```

It works but this is not the behaviour I am looking for.

**How it works right now**: Item 1 fades in > Item 2 fades in > Item 3 fades in

**How i would like it to work**: Item 1 fades in > Item 1 fades out > Item 2 fades in > Item 2 fades out > Item 3 fades in > Item 3 fades out

Comment: hey! did you find my suggestion any helpful? did it solve your problem? let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 3):

Does the below help?

***Snippet:***

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll('.item'), length = items.length;
var duration = 1;
var tl = new TimelineMax({ paused:true, repeat: -1, delay: duration * 0.5 });
for (var i = 0; i < length; i += 1) {
    tl.from(items[i], duration, { x: -20, opacity: 0, ease: Elastic.easeOut });
    tl.to(items[i], duration, { x: -20, opacity: 0, ease: Elastic.easeIn });
}
tl.play();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.17.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<div class="item"><h2>Item 1</h2></div>
<div class="item"><h2>Item 2</h2></div>
<div class="item"><h2>Item 3</h2></div>
```

If I am not wrong, [`.staggerFromTo()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/staggerFromTo/) doesn't help here because you need to add 2 tweens of the same element into the timeline first, one for *fading in* and one for *fading out*. Hence, a loop is used. And then the typical [`.from()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/from/) and [`.to()`](http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/TimelineMax/to/) methods are used from **GSAP** to achieve the *fade and slide* effect.

Also, I am not sure why you had a `delay` applied to each of the tweens. I have moved it into the initialisation of `TimelineMax` assuming that you want to delay the whole animation sequence before it first starts.

Hope this helps.